# External HDD Could not be Mount in Centos

Tags: networking, mount, centos-6

I  have an Transcend HDD in NTFS file system. By mistake I unmount it from centos. After this i am not able to connect it again. Now it is not showing icon for it.

Please help me, how to again mount it so that icon could be display. I need to write important data into it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think ntfs file-system will not support in CentOS. Once I faced same issue.

To mount ntfs file-system in CentOS follow below method.

Make sure you have the rpmforge or epel repo installed.

To enable epel repositary follow this method

```
For 32 bit
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

For 64 bit
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum update
```

```
yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
yum install ntfs-3g
```

Then Mount the External HDD

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/disk /mnt/disk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see attached disks by `fdisk -l`

you can also do `df -h` to show what disks are already mounted

Then, make a directory to mount to

```
mkdir /mnt/Diskname1
```

Then mount the disk as a location:

```
mount /dev/Diskname1 /mnt/Diskname1
```

If you want that to persist, edit fstab and you should be good.